# Baby Rudin, Example 1.1, proving irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers, motivation

In Principles of Mathematical Analysis, trying to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, we can read:

> Let $A$ be the set of all positive rationals $p$ such that $p^2<2$ and let B consist of all positive rationals $p$ such that $p^2>2$. We shall show that *A contains no largest number and B contains no smallest*.

I don't understand what this is proving. If I replace $p^2<2$ with $p^2<4$, I can prove that *A contains no largest number* as well. Surely, this does not prove that $\sqrt{4}$ is irrational.

What am I missing? Is this an erratum and we should read $p^2\leq 2$ instead of $p^2<2$?

Comment: The proof that $\sqrt{2}$ isn't rational precedes that part.  The part you are referencing is used for the existence of $\sqrt{2}$ in the real numbers as defined in the chapter 1 appendix.

Comment: @Brian Moehring. Interesting, but I could still paraphrase Gradient's objection here: If I replace $p^2 < 2$ with $p^2 < -1$, I can prove that $A$ *contains no largest number* as well. Surely, this does not prove that $\sqrt{-1}$ is real.

Comment: @Vincent Certainly not, but the cuts defined in the appendix are crucially neither empty nor all of $\mathbb{Q}$.  The set of rational solutions to $p^2<-1$ is empty so it doesn't correspond to a real number.

Comment: @Vincent they're not trying to prove that the number is real they're trying to prove that the rationals have gaps.

Comment: George Bergman has excellent notes on Rudin, which can be found here:  https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/ug.hndts/m104_Rudin_exs.pdf.  Page 3 of these notes contain some helpful comments about Rudin's proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: You are missing that $A$ and $B$ comprise all the rational numbers.  If $A = \{p|p^2 < 4\}$ and $B = \{q|q^2 > 4\}$ then $A$ and $B$ do not comprise all the rational numbers as $2\not \in A$ and $2 \not\in B$.  ... Replacing this with $A=\{p|p^2< -1\}=\emptyset$ and $B$ with $\{q|q^2 > -1\} =\mathbb Q$ does comprise all rationals but they are not both non-empty.   The point Rudin is making is we can partition $\mathbb Q$ into two non-empty disjoint sets $A$ and $B$ so that all the elements of $A$ are less than all the elements of $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the argument proves that $p^2=2$ is impossible but you have failed to prove that $p^2=4$ is impossible. Arguments build on previous statements so you can't evaluate a claim in isolation without considering the previous results.

In the section you reference they are trying to demonstrate that the rationals have gaps because $A$ has no greatest element, $B$ has no least element and we already know that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. This is meant to motivate the construction of the real numbers using Dedekind cuts.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was another proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

CyclotomicField's answer explains that the exposition is all about motivation.

A picture can be worth many words...

The OP knows $2^2 = 4$ and will agree that it is trivial to 'split' the rationals into two disjoint open rays abutting against a single rational number $2$:

$\tag 1  (-\infty, 2) \cup (2, +\infty) \subset \Bbb Q$

Exercise 1: Graph $\text{(1)}$
(use that 'little circle dot' at the $2$ spot and then use arrows for the left and right rays).

Now even though a solid line is used to graph the rational number line in the above exercise, that is actually a bit misleading...

Let

$\quad L = \{q \in \Bbb Q \mid \exists a \in \Bbb Q \text{ such that } (a \gt 0) \land (a^2 \lt 2) \land (q \le a)\}$

and

$\quad R = \{q \in \Bbb Q \mid \exists a \in \Bbb Q \text{ such that } (a \gt 0) \land (a^2 \gt 2) \land (q \ge a)\}$

Exercise 2: Observe that $L$ and $R$ are also open rays defined with $\Bbb Q$ as our universal set. Explain why these two open rays are 'abutting against' each other, but (playing a game of peek-a-boo), you don't see anything in the middle of them. Graph both $L$ and $R$ and put that 'little circle dot', uhh, (no one is looking), around $1.41$, and, of course, don't label it with $\sqrt 2$ (we don't have it in $\Bbb Q$).